# "Document is not defined" Webpack + React on Rails + Server Rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

Im use react_on_rails gem and im try render the component by the server.

When i use components directly from the app it works OK!

```
import Hello from "../components/Hello"

ReactOnRails.register({
  Hello
})
```

But when i try use a package, the app throws error.

```
import { Ballon } from "foo-package"
import Hello from "../components/Hello"

ReactOnRails.register({
  Ballon,
  Hello
})

ERROR in SERVER PRERENDERING
Encountered error: "ReferenceError: document is not defined"
```

Someone knows why?

Comment: The reason it's not works is the package you imported is not server-rendering friendly. In server side, node.js isn't a global variable. You can try use `document` in your Hello Component's `render` or `componentWillMount`, and same error will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found! The 'foo-package' uses a non isomorphic package. Its breaks the server rendering. The package is react-google-chart.

Answer (score 2):

window and document are global variables that are only available in a browser environment.

When you are rendering on the server you don't have that environment. You need to safeguard your code and skip invoking any functions on those objects when you are in a node.js environment. For example:

```
if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  // Do your document thing here
} else {
  console.log("We're on server")
}
```